# polynomial-time mapping reductions for NP

Tags: computer-science

I have already proven the transitive property for polynomial-time mapping reductions, that is:

> if A is reducible to B and B is reducible to C, then A is reducible to C.

So from this point, knowing that B is NP and A is polynomial-time mapping reducible to B, how should I prove A is also NP?

Answer (score 0):

B is in NP, so there is some Turing machine, let's call it M(B), which decides B in polynomial time. Furthermore, because A is polynomial-time reducible to B, there are TMs, let's call them M(R) and M(R'), which transform input instances of A into input instances of B, and outputs of B into outputs of A, both in polynomial time. Consider a TM constructed as follows:

1. Execute M(R) on the input tape and then reset the tape head
2. Execute M(B) on the input tape and then reset the tape head
3. Execute M(R') on the input tape and then reset the tape head

Each of these steps takes polynomial time and so the whole process takes polynomial time. Because nondeterministic Turing machines are closed under concatenation (by replacing halt_accept in the LHS with the initial state of the RHS), the computation can be done by a single nondeterministic Turing machine combining these steps. Thus, A can be decided by a nondeterministic Turing machine in polynomial time - the criterion for inclusion in NP.

Comment: Thanks, that's more than enough!